# Navigation bar not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

Here I have 2 views:

- WelcomeVC
- WebViewVC

First **AppDelegate** calls **WelcomeVC** through this code below:

```
- (void)presentWelcomeViewController 
    WelcomeViewController *welcomeViewController = [[WelcomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WelcomeViewController" bundle:nil];

    welcomeViewController.title = @"Welcome to My App";

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:welcomeViewController];
    navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    self.viewController = navController;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
}
```

So in **WelcomeVC**, navigation bar is not shown with `navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;`. In **WelcomeVC**, there is a button to call **WebViewVC** as detailed below:

```
- (IBAction)termsPressed:(id)sender {
    WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"Terms of Use");
    webViewController.urlPassed = @"http://.../term.html";
    webViewController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Terms of Use", nil);
    [webViewController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];    
}
```

When this button is pressed, I want it to call **WebViewVC** with navigation bar presented as I do `[webViewController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];` but what I found is **WebViewVC** is presented without navigation bar still. I also include viewDidLoad in **WebViewVC** as shown below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(screenSize.height == 480)
    {
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    }
    else if(screenSize.height == 568)
    {
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
    }

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlPassed]]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

Does anyone please help guide me where I am missing or doing wrong? That would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I found a solution by changing code for the button in **WelcomeVC**:

```
- (IBAction)termsPressed:(id)sender {
    WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"Terms of Use");
    webViewController.urlPassed = @"http://.../term.html";

    UINavigationController *webViewNavController =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:webViewController];

    webViewNavController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

    webViewNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:webViewNavController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

call

```
[webViewController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

In - viewWillAppear method

Also I recommend you update frame with

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Comment: viewWillAppear in webViewVC?

Comment: Can you please check, do you have navigationController object, when you in - viewWillAppear?

Comment: Your comment led me to a solution. You have my up-vote and thank you.