# Xcode back button missing

Tags: swift, xcode

I appear to have a problem in Xcode. On my storyboard it shows a back button, but when run in the simulator, not only does the back button not appear, the entire navigation bar is missing.

Can anyone offer any common issues which may cause this?

[image: xcode]

[image: simulator]

Comment: I've edited your question so it makes more sense. It would help if you could start by at least telling us which version of Xcode you have.

Comment: Are you using a `UINavigationController`? Can you show more of your Storyboard.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29899071/3151675.

Comment: The back button is being displayed by a `UINavigationController`. Do you have one in your project? Please provide _a lot more details_ to keep your downvote score from increasing and allow us to answer comprehensively.

Comment: yes, i link from UINavigationController (root view controller) to TabBarController (view controller) to ViewController (show)

Comment: Im new to swift and this platform

Comment: import Foundation
import UIKit

class InitialViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
    
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        get {
            return .lightContent
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

It could very possibly we that you do not have your constraints properly set. This can be done in the view controller editor menu. It is in the bottom right hand corner.